# What nginx.conf file should I configure?

Tags: performance, nginx, tuleap

I'm trying to *performance_tune* My Tuleap 11.8 Service which run on NginX server. I know what parameters to tune. But there's many **.conf** files there's:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/tuleap.conf
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
/usr/share/tuleap/src/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I'm confused which file should I configure?
And does it conflict with the others files?

Comment: Configuration is done below ˋ/etc/nginxˋ. Which file may depend on the parameters you want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I got it! the Main file is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and is including all the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` including `tuleap.conf`. So hopefully I'll be configuring the Main file which is `nginx.conf`.